# Updateable Text Field on watch face for wear 2.0

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to create a Text Field on a watch face that is updated every few seconds with data polled from an API. What is the best library to use for this? I want to design this as stand-alone, so I don't need it to be controlled by a separate app.

Comment: What is it you need a library for? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I suppose I mean, which android library is best. Do I need to make a complication for this, or can I use something simple like android.support.wearable.view, which I think is a library, if not what would you refer to it as?

Comment: any examples out there would be great. I've been having trouble finding any

Comment: You may want to check [Adding Complications to a Watch Face](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/complications.html#adding_complications_to_a_watch_face). This also discussed usable classes which are available in the wearable support library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the text to your **own** watch face, I would use the [TextRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/complications/rendering/TextRenderer.html) class in the wearable support library. It renders text on a canvas within specified bounds and readjusts the text to make it fit. It is usually intended for complication data, but you could use it on your own non-complication data.

You might think about exposing your data to the complication framework, so you could let any other watch face (not just your own) display your data. You can add a tap event, so a user can click into your app from the other watch faces. It is actually quite easy, check out the [Google I/O code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/data-providers/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) on how to do it.

If you do go that route (exposing data to the complication framework), you could also add support for displaying complication data (and now your data) on your own watch face. There is a code lab for that too ([here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/complications/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)), i.e., displaying complication data on your watch face.

Finally, if you just want to see the source code in a project that supports complications, you can check out the Analog watch face in the Google's [github repo for watch faces](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace).

Comment: Thanks you so much for this concise answer. This is the exact info I was looking for.